# Is it possible to rename ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, environment-variables, asp.net-core-webapi

In `Configure` method in `Startup` class of `ASP.NET Core WebAPI project`...

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
```

injected `IWebHostEnvironment` is driven by the value in the *ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT* environment variable.

Can we rename this variable?
If yes, Is it a good practice to rename it?

Comment: The real question is:  Why would you want to? You can sure use any name you want and just load your environment "manually" in your program.cs.... But why would you?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro For example, I want to run two web APIs on the same machine and run one in "production" mode, while the other one in "development" mode.

Comment: That is a really bad idea.  That is why it is called an "Environment".  Mixing environments it's recipe for disaster. Specially mixing things into your production environment.  In any case you do not need these environment variables at all.... Because you can set the actual environment you want in code by reading it from a file or hard code it if you want.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot really rename the names of the environment variables `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` or `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT`. Those are built into the default host builder that you will likely use when creating ASP.NET Core applications.

What you can do however is configure the host with your own configuration sources. That way, you can inject configurations from environment variables that do not follow standard names. For example, if you wanted to read the environment name from the environment variable `stage`, then you could modify the `CreateHostBuilder` to include a call to `ConfigureHostConfiguration` that modifies the configuration:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureHostConfiguration(c => {
            c.AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                ["Environment"] = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("stage"),
            });
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Note that if you call `ConfigureHostConfiguration` **before** `ConfigureWebHostDefaults`, then you will need to make sure that your `launchSettings.json` does not contain a configuration for the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable or your custom variable will be overwritten. You can also swap those two calls around to make your environment variable take precedence over the standard name. Of course this only applies in development (since there is no `launchSettings.json` in production).

To answer your final question: Is this a good idea? Probably not. Unless you need to do this for external reasons (e.g. to fit into existing deployment processes you don’t have control over), you should stick to the default names to make sure that all involved parties understand the impact properly.

And just to clarify this: Both `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` and `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` are good to use and the latter is not going away any time soon.

Comment: This answer is exactly correct. If you use the default builder (and you should) then `ConfigureHostConfiguration` is when you should override the value for "Environment" using whatever method you prefer. But you need to bear in mind that the default builder and web host builder may also set this value. However there is also a UseEnvironment extension method that also does this for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in way to set the environment for the application:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseEnvironment("WHAT EVER YOU WANT")//set it for this app
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
              webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

As you can see you can use 'UseEnvironment("MY COOL ENVIRONMENT")' to set it to what ever you want.

And the source of it can be any environment variable, file, database, hard coded... any thing you can think of.

Here is some documentation.  Scroll to the section called [EnvironmentName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to find information about it.

Comment: Note that this sets a _value_ for the environment, essentially hard-coding ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT.  From that link: "Framework-defined values include Development, Staging, and Production."

Comment: @ladenedge the value does not need to be hardcoded.... it could come from any source.  Also Development, Staging, Production are just examples... You can call your environments whatever you want. Also this method does NOT set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable... It simply overrides the value for the current application.